# $f \geq 0$ on $[0, 1]$ and $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx = b-a$ for all $[a, b] \subset [0, 1]$ then $f = 1$ a.e.

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $f \geq 0$ be measurable on $[0, 1]$ with $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx = b-a$ for all $[a, b] \subset [0, 1]$. Show $f = 1$ a.e.

**Attempt:** Fix $n > 1$ and let $A_{j} := \{1-\frac{j+1}{n} \leq f < 1-\frac{j}{n}\}$ for $0 \leq j < n$. First note

$$1 = \int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx = \int_{f=1} f(x) dx + \int_{0 \leq f < 1} f(x) dx = 1 + \int_{0 \leq f < 1} f(x) dx,$$

whence $\int_{0 \leq f < 1} f(x) dx = 0$. Therefore

$$0 = \int_{0 \leq f < 1} f(x) dx \geq \int_{A_{j}} f(x) dx \geq \left(1 - \frac{j+1}{n}\right)\mu(A_{j}),$$

and so $\mu(A_{j}) = 0$ when $j < n-1$. Now,

$$\mu(0 \leq f < 1) = \mu\left(\bigcup_{j} A_{j}\right) = \sum_{j} \mu(A_{j}) = \mu(A_{n-1}).$$

Note $A_{n-1} = \{0 \leq f < \frac{1}{n}\}$.

**Where I'm Stuck:** I want to show $\mu(A_{n-1}) \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. I know that $\int_{A_{n-1}} f(x) dx \rightarrow 0$, but this doesn't help!

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, you can apply [Zero integral of measurable $f$ on every interval implies $f=0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1659993/zero-integral-of-measurable-f-on-every-interval-implies-f-0) to $f(x) - x$.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to show that $|f(x) - 1| = 0$ a.e.?

Comment: @MartinR Ah okay, so I could let $g := f-1$ and say $\int_{a}^{b} g = 0$ $\forall [a, b] \subset [0, 1]$ $\implies$ $g = 0$ a.e., but I'm not sure this is a result I can assume. However, I may be able to work better with the sets $\{g > 1/n\}$ and $\{g < 1/n\}$....

Comment: Okay I can use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1659993/zero-integral-of-measurable-f-on-every-interval-implies-f-0) nifty trick.